# C++ Struct in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm using a DLL written in C++ in my C# project by using DllImport and one of the functions I'm using looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("dds.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int Par(
        ddTableResults2 tableResult,
        ref parResults ParResult,
        int vul
    );
```

The parResults struct is defined in C++ like this:

```
struct parResults {
  /* index = 0 is NS view and index = 1 
     is EW view. By 'view' is here meant 
     which side that starts the bidding. */
  char          parScore[2][16];
  char          parContractsString[2][128]; 
};
```

The start of the C++ function

```
int STDCALL Par(struct ddTableResults * tablep, struct parResults *presp, 
    int vulnerable)
```

How should I define the above struct in C# to able to send that struct as en reference into the DLL function?

This is what I have tried but don't work at all and I just get a Access Violation Error

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct parResults
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public char[,] parScore;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public char[,] parContractsString;

        public parResults(int x)
        {
            parScore = new char[2,16];
            parContractsString = new char[2,128];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think to begin with you should post the true definition of the C++ struct, and the function that you are importing. The fake version of the struct that you posted leaves us wondering what else changed from the code that compiles and the code that you posted.

Comment: I will see if I can find it!

Comment: What about `struct ddTableResults`? How is that declared in C++ and C#. Why is that not passed by ref in the C#?

Comment: I'm using some open source and documentation is limited; http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/dds270-src.zip but I managed to get it to work if using a one dimensional array and ref for the ddTableResult also

Comment: Which way does the data flow? From C# down to the native library. Or in the other direction? Or in both directions. I don't particularly want to grub around in some open source off-site link. I think that's for you to do and then provide the declarations here in the question. Thanks for the edits so far.

Comment: I think something with the struct declaration is wrong. You need a 2D array, but with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]` you fix one dimension only. I think I've never used 2D arrays in interop, so I'm not sure about how that should work.

Comment: @PMF It's hard to make work. It's very broken at the moment. We still need to know which way the data flows.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a tricky struct to marshal in C#. There are various ways to attempt it, but I think that it will be cleanest to represent the character arrays as byte arrays and marshal to and from strings by hand. Here is a demonstration of what I mean:

**C++**

```
#include <cstring>

struct parResults {
    char          parScore[2][16];
    char          parContractsString[2][128];
};

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void foo(struct parResults *res)
    {
        strcpy(res->parScore[0], res->parContractsString[0]);
        strcpy(res->parScore[1], res->parContractsString[1]);
    }
}
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        class parResults 
        {
            private const int parScoreCount = 2;
            private const int parScoreLen = 16;
            private const int parContractsStringCount = 2;
            private const int parContractsStringLen = 128;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, 
                SizeConst = parScoreCount * parScoreLen)]
            private byte[] parScoreBuff;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, 
                SizeConst = parContractsStringCount * parContractsStringLen)]
            private byte[] parContractsStringBuff;

            public string getParScore(int index)
            {
                string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(parScoreBuff, 
                    index * parScoreLen, parScoreLen);
                int len = str.IndexOf('\0');
                if (len != -1)
                    str = str.Substring(0, len);
                return str;
            }

            public void setParScore(int index, string value)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
                int len = Math.Min(bytes.Length, parScoreLen);
                Array.Copy(bytes, 0, parScoreBuff, index * parScoreLen, len);
                Array.Clear(parScoreBuff, index * parScoreLen + len,
                    parScoreLen - len);
            }

            public string parContractsString(int index)
            {
                string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(parContractsStringBuff,
                    index * parContractsStringLen, parContractsStringLen);
                int len = str.IndexOf('\0');
                if (len != -1)
                    str = str.Substring(0, len);
                return str;
            }

            public void setParContractsString(int index, string value)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
                int len = Math.Min(bytes.Length, parContractsStringLen);
                Array.Copy(bytes, 0, parContractsStringBuff,
                    index * parContractsStringLen, len);
                Array.Clear(parContractsStringBuff, 
                    index * parContractsStringLen + len,
                    parContractsStringLen - len);
            }

            public parResults()
            {
                parScoreBuff = new byte[parScoreCount * parScoreLen];
                parContractsStringBuff = 
                    new byte[parContractsStringCount * parContractsStringLen];
            }
        };

        [DllImport(@"...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void foo([In,Out] parResults res);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            parResults res = new parResults();
            res.setParContractsString(0, "foo");
            res.setParContractsString(1, "bar");
            foo(res);
            Console.WriteLine(res.getParScore(0));
            Console.WriteLine(res.getParScore(1));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here I've used a class to represent the struct. Since a class in C# is a reference, we don't declare the parameters of that type with `ref`. I've also used `__cdecl` for convenience to avoid having to work out what the decorated name of the function would be. But your library used `__stdcall` and so you need to stick to that.

The class demonstrates sending data in both directions. You could probably simplify the code if the data flow was more restricted.