# Convert c++ struct to c# struct. Error output

Tags: c#, c++, struct, dll, export

My C++ `dll` has two struct.

C++:

```
typedef struct interface_info {
    DWORD   index;
    DWORD   ipv4Addr;
    BYTE    macAddr[6];
    DWORD   gateway;
}I_INFO;

typedef struct user_info {
    DWORD   uniqueid;
    BYTE    userid[32];
    BYTE    pwd[32];
    BYTE    info[5][64];        
}U_INFO;
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct I_INFO
{
    public uint Index;
    public uint ipv4Addr;   
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public byte[] macAddr;   
    public uint gateway;
}; 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct U_INFO
{
    public uint uniqueid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] userid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] pwd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 320)]
    public byte[] info;
};
```

I'm calling this method:

C++:

```
void GetNetworkInfo(I_INFO *n); // Show interface Info
dword RegNewUser(U_INFO *u);    // Save to test.ini
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("TestNet.dll")]
public static extern void GetNetworkInfo(ref I_INFO n);
[DllImport("TestNet.dll")]
public static extern uint RegNewUser(ref U_INFO u);
```

I'm calling this way:
C#:

```
I_INFO ii = new I_INFO();
GetNetworkInfo(ref ii);

MessageBox.Show(ii.index+ "\n"
          + Long2ip(ii.ipAddr) + "\n"
          + Long2ip(ii.gateway) + "\n"
          + Bytes2Str(ii.macAddr);
....

I_INFOuser = new I_INFO
{
    uid = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testUser"),
    pwd = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testPassword"),
    info = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world!")
};
try
{
    RegNewUser(ref user);
}
catch(Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
}
```

The output is:

[image: GetNetworkInfo]

[image: RegNewUser]

`GetNetworkInfo` returns normal results, but `RegNewUser` outputs this error:

> Error: Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there padding between the `macAddr` and the `gateway` members?  Is the layout exactly the same between C# and C++?  You may want to move the byte array as the last member.

Comment: There is no padding between members.
The struct size is the same between C# and C++.

Comment: I've addressed this issue with the following answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510206/c-struct-in-c-sharp?rq=1)